nothing being displayed after hosting
Before hosting my site everything was being displayed as it should and was working properly but after hosting the site on Firebase nothing was being displayed afterwards except a quick glimpse of the main page just for a frame.
These are the errors that i get on the console:

That's how the main page should look:

And that's how it's displayed after hosting:

I checked the jQuery error and it said that it's something with the index.html file but after fixing it it's still the same.
index.html
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

That's all I have but if you need more information in order to help me fix it I'd provide it. Thanks in advance!
Edit: I included jQuery before Bootstrap and made it up to date but the error is still there. I'm also showing the folders to see that the code is in that file but it's wrong in the site.



I don't see that you took the advice of the error message and put jquery before bootstrap.  What you're showing still has them in the wrong order.  Also, you seem to be using two different versions of bootstrap from different sources - that doesn't make sense at all.

I fixed it but it's still the same error

Your question should be showing the "fixed" code so we can see what you actually did.  We can't see that you did the right thing.
